# Tkinter: Wait for either of multiple buttons to be pressed and delete all buttons after that

Tags: python, user-interface, asynchronous, button, tkinter

I have an interface with two buttons. They have mutually exclusive actions and are generated when a certain condition in a background for-loop is met. The user is supposed to click one of them and then the buttons are supposed to disappear. They might reappear when the condition is met again in the background running for-loop. You can think of the buttons of doing a "choose exactly one of these..." type thing. The for-loop in the background needs to wait for the user input. Therefore, I use the `wait_variable` method on the buttons.

To model this I wrote this MWE:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

a, b = 0, 0

var = tk.IntVar()

def Aaction():
    global a
    a += 1
    var.set(var.get()+1)
    b1.destroy()
    b2.destroy()

def Baction():
    global b
    b += 1
    var.set(var.get()+1)
    b1.destroy()
    b2.destroy()

# this happens before A and B are displayed
print('some code executing')

b1 = tk.Button(root, text='A', command=Aaction)
b1.pack()

b2 = tk.Button(root, text='B', command=Baction)
b2.pack()

b1.wait_variable(var)
print('b1 finsihed waiting')
b2.wait_variable(var) # what happens to this? `b2` is deleted when `b` is clicked. so...?
print('b2 finsihed waiting') # this is never reached

# this should happen after either A or B was clicked
print('some more code executing')

root.mainloop()
```

This code does not what I intend, but it is an abstraction of how I tried to solve this in my code. My question is: How do you solve this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Could something like this work?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def Aaction():
    b1.destroy()
    b2.destroy()
    do_later()

def Baction():
    b1.destroy()
    b2.destroy()
    do_later()

# this happens before A and B are displayed
print('some code executing')

b1 = tk.Button(root, text='A', command=Aaction)
b1.pack()

b2 = tk.Button(root, text='B', command=Baction)
b2.pack()

# this should happen after either A or B was clicked
def do_later():
    print('some more code executing')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hardly. Is there really no canonical solution to something like this?

Comment: And say I did it like that: What state do I leave the background for-loop in that corresponds to "some code executing" if I restart it each time A or B is pressed? It will terminate in for the "last" call, since A and B remove differences in two lists and the loop runs through, when there are no differences. But what state are all the previous calls in?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`root.wait_variable(var)`

instead of

```
b1.wait_variable(var)
print('b1 finsihed waiting')
b2.wait_variable(var)
print('b2 finsihed waiting')
```